# No puedo entrar en PHPMyAdmin sin contraseña teniendo el AllowNoPassword = true

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Me descargué Xampp para Windows 10, para tener un servidor local y experimentar con PHP. A pesar de que tuve muchos contratiempos, logré llegar hasta un punto en el cual no logro hallar una solución por mucho que navegue en la red.

Entro en localhost/phpmyadmin... introduzco el usuario root sin contraseña y me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error no se encuentra en el archivo config.inc.php, ya que lo tengo configurado de esta manera:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp'; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']= 'root'; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql'; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

¿Qué es lo que puede estar fallando y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Tu OS es Ubuntu?

Comment: Perdón por no ponerlo: Mi OS es windows 10

Comment: En algunos casos se escribe así: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;` Y verifica que estás modificando el archivo de configuraciones en la ruta correcta, no sea que esté leyendo **otro** en otra ruta. En otros casos hay que agregar también: `if (!empty($dbname)) {
    // other configuration options
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
    // it should be placed before the following line
    $i++;
}`

Comment: Cambiándolo por $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true; hace lo mismo. Respecto al directorio estoy usando este: C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin y el programa que está funcionando es este: https://gyazo.com/3741d825f4e4182a41fce933437f2aaa es primera vez que lo uso... o sea que se me estará pasando una chorrada... el problema es que he probado mil y un cosas y no sé qué falla

Comment: Deberías incluir las cosas que hayas intentado, para evitar comprobar las mismas cosas que ya probaste y fallaron

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76186/no-puedo-conectarme-a-phpmyadmin-después-de-la-instalación-tengo-el-acceso-dene/110203#110203

Answer (score 3):

Yo tenía el mismo problema y tan solo hay que entrar en el archivo config.sample.inc.php, poner la línea del 'AllowNoPassword' a 'true', cambiar el nombre del archivo a 'config.inc.php'.
Recuerda reiniciar el servicio para que se apliquen los cambios y cuando vuelvas a intentarlo te funcionará. .