# Acceso denegado a phpMyAdmin después de la instalación

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Instale XAMPP 3.2.2 pero me sale este error de acceso denegado al intentar ingresar a phpMyAdmin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué ocurre ese error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: por que necesitas una captura de pantalla para mostrarnos un error de solo texto? copia el texto y pegalo...

Comment: Hice una pregunta y copie el texto q me salía.. pero administración No les parecía la forma de hacer mi pregunta

Comment: Esta tampoco es la forma de preguntar, de echo es aun peor, esta es una guía de como deberían de ser las preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Despues de cambiar puertos a 8080 y 3307. Intento ingresar a phpmyadmin y me sale este ERROR.  #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)                                                                      phpMyAdmin intentó conectarse con el servidor MySQL, y el servidor rechazó esta conexión. Deberá revisar el host, nombre de usuario y contraseña en config.inc.php y asegurarse que corresponden con la información provista por el administrador del servidor MySQL.

Comment: desde que dirección entras? http://localhost/phpmyadmin/?

Comment: Instale xampp 3.2.2 a mi pc ahora cambie puertos, ahora trato de ingresar al.. localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ y me devuelve lo que comenté anteriormente.